# Is Yesod's Handler Monad an instance of MonadBaseControl IO?

Tags: haskell, yesod, monad-transformers

I would like to use the `withResource :: MonadBaseControl IO m => Pool a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`  from the [Data.Pool](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resource-pool-0.2.3.2/docs/Data-Pool.html#v:withResource) library in my handler code.  I am trying to determine if `Handler` is an instance of [`MonadBaseControl IO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl), but I'm having a hard time finding the exact place that `Handler` is defined.

Is [Yesod's `Handler` Monad](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/yesods-monads) (as created by `mkYesodData`) an instance of `MonadBaseControl IO` or can it easily be made into one?

Comment: I wanted to ask: which `Handler` do you mean? But I guess that is part of your question. How did you get access to this `Handler`? What are your imports? Did you follow some learning resource that mentions this `Handler`?

Comment: The `Handler` Monad that is created by `mkYesodData` in the standard Yesod setup. It is the fact that this monad is created by a Template that makes this such a hard thing to track down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `Handler` does not have a `MonadBaseControl IO` instance.

However, it's basically a reader, so it's not too difficult to write one.

Assuming you're using the scaffolded site, the following should work.  Add some extensions and imports to the top of `Foundation`:

```
import Control.Monad.Base
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import Yesod.Core.Types (HandlerFor(..))
```

In some convenient place after the `mkYesodData` statement, add the instances:

```
instance MonadBase IO Handler where
  liftBase = liftIO
instance MonadBaseControl IO Handler where
  type StM Handler a = a
  liftBaseWith ioAct = HandlerFor $ \handlerData ->
    ioAct (\handlerAct -> unHandlerFor handlerAct handlerData)
  restoreM = return
```

I have no idea if what you're *generally* trying to do is a good idea or not, but that should get things to type-check.

Comment: "I have no idea if what you're generally trying to do is a good idea or not," The `Persistent` implementation for MongoDB is both out of date and a poor fit for document databases. I'm dropping down a level and using the Haskell MongoDB driver directly.  I'm adding a pool of MongoDB `Pipes` to `App`.  #ReinventingTheWheel